# Flutter & Firebase: Is there a way I can return a specific field from firebase to a function?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[users>user Id then:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPtpA.png)

My aim is to return the user's key from the document and then be able to use that key in other functions.

```
  getUsersKey() async {
   final uid = await getCurrentUser();
   Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).get();
   // Then I want to return the userKey feild 
  }
```

Comment: This question does not apply to Firebase-Realtime-Database. Please tag correctly.

Comment: do you want to get the document id?

Comment: No, I want to get one of the fields (userKey). If you click on the link you can see the field I want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the code below:

```
 Future<void> getUsersKey() async {
   final uid = await getCurrentUser();

 DocumentSnapshot snapshot = 
 await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).get();
  userKey = snapshot.data['userKey'] //you can get any field value you want by writing the exact fieldName in the data[fieldName]
  }
```

Comment: Don't you just love Stack Overflow! Thank you Morez, it's working.

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer so others know it works. Thanks :)